# React-native 0.49 CheckBox How to change the prop : value ?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, react-native

I'm trying to understand how to change the value of a checkbox that is new in React-native 0.49.

```
            <CheckBox
            value = {this.state.value}
            onValueChange= {(value) => this.toggleCheckBox(value)}
            />
```

And this is my toggleCheckbox function

```
toggleCheckBox(data){
   this.setProps({
     value : data
});
```

The question is .. the function onValueChange only works once and once only. the toggleCheckBox is called only once also I cant figure out how to update the value of checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setState`.

```js
toggleCheckBox(data){
   this.setState({value: data});
}
```

`props` is uni-direction and cannot be modified.